# How to prevent usage of object in ellipsis

Tags: c++

Is there a way to prevent the pass an object to an ellipsis?

Example:

The ellipsis is used in the following function

```
int my_printf( const char * format, ... );
```

And there is an object of some type:

```
struct Text
{
  const char * c_str();
};
Text text;
```

Is it possible to change `struct Text` so that the following does not compile?

```
my_printf("%s", text ); // should fail to compile
my_printf("%s", text.c_str() ); // this was the intention
```

Changing `my_printf` to use variadic template arguments instead of an ellipsis is not an option.

Comment: You could add a `static_assert` within the function based on the type of the second arg e.g. `static_assert(!std::same<T, Text>::value)`.

Comment: What’s the purpose? At the moment the question is pretty vague, and the face value answer at the moment is “no”, but with more details there might be a way.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I have extended the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Mansoor: I don't understand how to add this.

Comment: @rustyx: any direct use of text in an ellipsis. Also when multiple ellipsis arguments are used.

Comment: On GCC & Clang, [`__attribute__((format(...)))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) might help. MSVC probably has something similar.

Comment: Seeing as how it's tagged C++, why are we not using std::ostream and overloading the stream extraction/insertion operators? All this char* and printf(...) stuff will drive you nuts.

Comment: int my_printf( const char * format, Text const & text,  ... ) then pass text.c_str() to the other version or have a compile time error if you want.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Good option in case of a printf-like usage of ellipsis.

Comment: @QuentinUK any usage of the object in an **ellipsis** should be prevented: e.g. my_printf("%d %s", 3, text ), my_printf("%d %d %s", 3, 4, text ), ...

Comment: Is using a variadic template an option?

Answer (score 0):

Use a static assert:

```
#include <type_traits>

// test all parameters for being true
template<typename ... Args>
constexpr bool all(Args ... args) { 
    return (... && args); 
}

// test if it's a class, error message has the name of the class
template<typename T>
struct not_an_object {
    static const bool value = !std::is_class<T>::value;
    static_assert(value, "no classes please");
};

// won't compile if there's a class object in the parameters
template<typename ... Ts, typename = 
std::enable_if_t<all(not_an_object<Ts>::value ...)>>
void a_print(char const*fmt, Ts ... e){
    my_printf(fmt, e...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fine solution. A variadic template seems to be the way to go. I assume it will not give any overhead on code size.

Comment: @hpc64 For no extra code turn on optimization to inline the function call, then there is no overhead. -O2 or higher for clang. If you are worried about code size you can compare different things very quickly with Compiler Explorer https://godbolt.org/z/dkmpX_

Answer (score 0):

In case deleting the copy constructor is an option the usage in ellipsis results in an error.
Unfortunately declaring the copy constructor as explicit does not result in an error.

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct A
{
  A( const  A & ) = delete;
  //explicit A( const  A & ) = default;
  A() {}
  int m = 3;
};


int main ()
{
  A a;
  printf("%d", a); // error
}
```